# What is updateValueAndValidity

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

[These docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html) state the following:

> If emitEvent is true, this change will cause a valueChanges event on
>   the FormControl to be emitted. This defaults to true (as it falls
>   through to updateValueAndValidity).

What is this `updateValueAndValidity`?

Comment: What is unclear with this explanation?

Comment: Lots! When exactly are you supposed to use it. When aren't you supposed to use it!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can subscribe to value changes of a control or the whole form.

`updateValueAndValidity` allows you to modify the value of one or more form controls and the flag allows you to specify if you want this to emit the value to `valueChanges` subscribers.

Comment: thanks, I don't see where `updateValueAndValidity` should be configured

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html#!#updateValueAndValidity-anchor

Comment: I have a required field, after I clear the validity using clearValidators() the required validator is not in effect and my form has no errors, I also set the required validity with setValidators([Validators.required]) and it updates right away. Do I still need to invoke updateValueAndValidity()? The form control is clearing and updating validity even without it.

Comment: You only need to call it if you want behavior different from the default behavior.

Answer (score 23):

The source code can be helpful to clear up exactly what it's doing:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts

Currently it seems to be doing the following (this list is based on method names):

- 'Set initial status' - which makes `.status` 'VALID' except if ALL controls are disabled, in which case it makes it 'DISABLED'
- 'Updates value' - this seems to set `.value` if the control is enabled, or clear it if disabled.
- 'Runs validator' - this updates the whole error object. So custom errors would be cleared if you'd set any.
- 'Cancel subscriptions' - stops any async validators running at the time
- 'Emit' event - (if emitEvent != false in options). This is just the `value` and `status` normal form events.
- Updates parent with same rules - unless `onlySelf` is set.

Note: it doesn't go *down* the tree, only up.

I wish they'd put something like this in [the docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updatevalueandvalidity). They currently say 'Recalculates the value and validation status of the control.' which isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: that is a very catchy line `this updates the whole error object. So custom errors would be cleared if you'd set any`

Answer (score 5):

The `updateValueAndValidity()` method belongs to the AbstractFormControl class, used to validate your forms programmatically.

Basically, when you add or remove a validator at run time, you must call `updateValueAndValidity()` for the new validation to take effect.