# Angular observable updated too early after FormGroup added

Tags: angular, rxjs

Sorry, I'm not even sure if this is the right title for my question. I tried to keep [the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmkkkv?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts) as light as possible.

Basically, I have a FormArray of FormGroups that each consist of an Angular Material Autocomplete. I want the options for the autocompletes to be an Observable so that I can update the entire list of options whenever one of the FormGroups in the array is changed - basically, whenever an option is selected I don't want it to be able to be selected by any of the other FormGroup's in the array.

But, and this is where my new-ness to angular will shine, I am updating the list of options on `valueChanges`, but when I push a new FormGroup on the array, I need a timeout that triggers a second `valueChanges` in order for the autocomplete options to show up at all. If I don't have it in there, then the list doesn't show up in the most recently added FormGroup.

**Why is this?**

The code is [here on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmkkkv?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Just click Add Input and you'll see a list of users in the autocomplete, but if you comment out line 72 and click Add Input, you won't see the list in the most recently added Form Group.

**EDIT**

It's going to be way easier to view the question by looking at the code on stackblitz, but because I got downvoted and close suggested, here's the component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs'

const users = [
    {
        id:1,
        name:'user1',
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:'user2',
    },
    {
        id:3,
        name:'user3',
    }
]

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  usersForm: FormArray;  
  users = users;
  filteredUsers: Observable<any>;
  selectedUsers = [];
  canAddInput = true;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.usersForm = this.fb.array([]);

    this
        .usersForm
        .valueChanges
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.selectedUsers = data.map(d => d.userNameSelector).filter(d => !!d);
            this.canAddInput = this.getUnselectedUsers().length !== 0 && this.usersForm.controls.length < this.users.length
        })

    //filtered users is an observable 
    this.filteredUsers = this
        .usersForm
        .valueChanges
        .pipe(
            switchMap(() => of(this.getUnselectedUsers()))
        )

   }

   getUnselectedUsers()
   {
    //console.log(this.users.filter(u => this._isNotSelectedUser(u.name)));
    return this.users.filter(u => this._isNotSelectedUser(u.name));
   }

  _isNotSelectedUser = user => !this.selectedUsers.includes(user)

  addInput() {
    this.usersForm.push(this.fb.group({userNameSelector:null}));

    //why do I need this - it triggers usersForm.valueChanges and filteredUsers is updated, but won't the code work without it why?
    setTimeout(() => this.usersForm.updateValueAndValidity(),1);
  }

  removeInput = idx => this.usersForm.removeAt(idx)

}
```

And the HTML:

```
    <form class="example-form" [formGroup]='usersForm'>
  <div *ngIf="usersForm.controls">
    <div
      *ngFor="let ctrlName of usersForm.controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">

      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input 
          matInput 
          placeholder="Choose a user" 
          [matAutocomplete]="auto"
          formControlName="userNameSelector"
        >
      </mat-form-field>
      <!-- <span>Your choice is: {{usersForm.get(input.name).value | json}}</span> -->

      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option 
            <!-- this async pipe is going to be important here -->
            *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers | async" 
            [value]="user.name"
          >
            <span>{{ user.name }}</span>
          </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
      <button 
        mat-raised-button 
        color="warn"
        (click)="removeInput(i)"
      >Remove Input</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button 
    *ngIf="canAddInput"
    mat-raised-button color="primary"
    (click)="addInput()"
  >Add Input</button>
</form>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197806/what-is-updatevalueandvalidity

Comment: @Chellappan - doesn't really answer my question. I knew I had to trigger `valueChanges` in my code, but I still don't know **why** I had to trigger `valueChanges`. It's a timing thing, for sure, but I'd like somebody to ELI5 because, from looking at the code, I don't know why the `valueChanges` event should be needed.

Comment: @Adam, at first time you push the new control, Angular add the autocomplete, but it's necesary a "second round" if you want "fill" the "filteredUsers" of the new control because is a observable and you not subscribe yet. If your filteredUsers was not an observable (simply in the first changeValues.subscribe make this.filteredUsers=this.getUnselectedUsers() - and remove the "| async"- in the mat-autocompleted) you needn't make the updateValueAndValidity

Comment: @Eliseo - you nailed it. I'm new to observables (is it that obvious?). Thanks!