# angular reactive forms - Unable to set custom validation massage in textfield onSubmit()

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am trying to set error msg to branchId Input text field which is not working on first click. 
Next time when I click submit it shows the error massage

My form

```js
   ngOnInit() {
     this.form = this.fb.group({
       BRANCH_ID: ['', 
          [   Validators.required,
              .....
           ],
        ]

   this.form.controls.branchId.valueChanges
       .subscribe(uploadBranchId => {
           if (uploadBranchId === '1234') {
                 this.form.controls.branchId.setErrors({'salesBranch': true})
              }
         });
    }
```

my error store library

```js
    branchId: {
       ....
      salesBranch: 'Please provide valid branchId',
    },
```

Form Submit event

```js
    onSubmit(){

    combineWithStream.call(
      this,
      masterErrorProgramme({
        fieldMap: this.fieldMap,
        controls: this.form.controls,
        errorStore: this.errorStore,
        scrollToError: true,
        formId: ''
      }).fieldMap
    );
    if (this.form.valid) {
     this.branchId = this.form.controls.branchId.value;
     // check branchId in Database
     this.serviceName.pipe(first()).subscribe((res) => {
     // If branchId is not found in Database
       if (res == "ID_NOT_FOUND") {
            this.form.controls.branchId.setErrors({'salesBranch': true})
       } else{
            this._router.navigate(somePath)
       }
      })
   }
  }
```

the first subscribe even works perfectly fine want same thing happens in onSubmit(). `this.form.controls.branchId.setErrors({'salesBranch': true})` in formmControls it is setting

```
errors:
salesBranch: true
__proto__: Object
```

but not updating in UI/browser.
Please help.

Comment: Try this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197806/what-is-updatevalueandvalidity

Comment: @Chellappan doing `this.form.controls.branchId.setErrors({'salesBranch': true}); this.form.controls.branchId.updateValueAndValidity();` is setting form as valid `enabled: (...)
errors: null
invalid: (...)
parent: (...)
pending: (...)
pristine: false
root: (...)
status: "VALID"`

Comment: can you create stackblitz?