# Angular not resetting validators

Tags: angular, angular6

Angular 6:

I have this form builder:

```
this.issuerDetails = this.formBuilder.group({
  paymentInstruction: ['', [Validators.required]],
  subscriptionTemplateHtml: ['', [Validators.required]],
});
```

with this getter

```
get issuerDetailsForm() { return this.issuerDetails.controls; }
```

down the road I remove the validators, and reset the value / set to pristine

```
this.issuerDetailsForm.subscriptionTemplateHtml.clearValidators();
this.issuerDetailsForm.subscriptionTemplateHtml.reset();
this.issuerDetailsForm.paymentInstruction.clearValidators();
this.issuerDetailsForm.paymentInstruction.reset();
```

When I go to re-enable these validators

```
this.issuerDetailsForm.subscriptionTemplateHtml.setValidators(Validators.required);
this.issuerDetailsForm.paymentInstruction.setValidators(Validators.required);
```

They aren't being triggered properly on form submission by the user

Why is this?

Comment: I don't understand. You are trying to reset issuerDetailsForm, which is not defined. Intead, you need to reset issuerDetails. Any way, updateValueAndValidity() will help you. this.issuerDetails.updateValueAndValidity() will help you here.

Comment: ah right, I have a getter too down the line. Updated the question with new information

Answer (score 0):

When a validator needs to be reset, `updateValueAndValidity` must be ran to reset the validators

so after all this code add this:

```
this.issuerDetailsForm.subscriptionTemplateHtml.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true });
this.issuerDetailsForm.paymentInstruction.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true });
```

It runs the validator and clears out any prior states

[What is updateValueAndValidity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197806/what-is-updatevalueandvalidity)

Answer (score 0):

Below code might help:

```
this.issuerDetails = this.formBuilder.group({
  paymentInstruction: ['', [Validators.required]],
  subscriptionTemplateHtml: ['', [Validators.required]],
});
```

For reset:

```
this.issuerDetails.reset();
this.issuerDetails.updateValueAndValidity();
```