# Update input type time based on updated FormControl using PatchValue or SetValue in Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have a form group with 3 inputs. The first input is a time input and the other 2 are custom form components. I setup a form.patchValue which updates the form values as seen below, however it does not update the UI, the time input is still empty.

How can I use patchValue to update the input ?

[image]

```js
    this.scheduleAutoReportForm = new FormGroup(
      {
        reportAt: new FormControl( '12:00' , Validators.required),
        days: new FormControl([],Validators.required),
        email: new FormControl([],[Validators.required])
      }
    );

    this.scheduleAutoReportForm.patchValue({
      reportAt: '24:00',
      days:["2","4"],
      email: ['placeholder@gmail.com'] 
    });

this.ref.detectChanges();
```

**Update**

I experimented and it turns out that the textbox gets updated but not the time.

[image]

```html
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="h-primary modal-title">Schedule Auto Report</h4>
    <mh1-icon-button [icon]="faTimes" [iconClasses]="['btn', 'btn-sm', 'mx-0']" iconSize="lg" (click)="closeModal()">
    </mh1-icon-button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body card">
    <!-- This is where the form starts -->
    <form [formGroup]='scheduleAutoReportForm' (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()'>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <label for="reportAt" ><h5>Send Report At:</h5></label>
          <input type="time" name='reportAt' formControlName='reportAt' class="form-control" required>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <label for="test" >test</label>
          <input type="text" name='test' formControlName='test' class="form-control" >
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-12">
        <sentryx-day-selector formControlName="days"></sentryx-day-selector>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class='col-12'>
          <sentryx-email-chips formControlName="email"></sentryx-email-chips>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-secondary"
            [disabled]="!scheduleAutoReportForm.valid">Submit</button>
          <button type="cancel" class="btn btn-md btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer card">
    {{scheduleAutoReportForm.value | json}}
    {{schedule | json}}
  </div>
```

Comment: For some reason the HTML page was not updating. restarting NPM did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling updateValueAndValidity() after patching the value?
See

[What is updateValueAndValidity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197806/what-is-updatevalueandvalidity/50349994)

Comment: why do you think that would be useful ?

Comment: I tried `this.scheduleAutoReportForm.get('reportAt').updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false });` it didnt work

Comment: Could you Post the html and the complete component then? My other guess would be something is not correct on the value you are setting. Formcontrols and groups are annoying to handle sometimes.

Comment: so I experimented with it and its that I am using a time input. I made a textbox and that gets populated