# Angular updateValueAndValidity() doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have simple form:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
  <input type="radio" id="enabled" formControlName="enabled"
    [value]="true" [checked]="form.controls.enabled.value == true"
    (click)="setValidators()">
  <label for="enabled">Enable</label>

  <input type="radio" id="disabled" formControlName="enabled"
    [value]="false" [checked]="form.controls.enabled.value == false"
    (click)="clearValidators()">
  <label for="disabled">Disable</label>

  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" formControlName="text">
  <button type="submit" 
    [disabled]="!form.valid">Save Changes</button>
</form>
```

and Angular component code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.buildForm();
}

buildForm() {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    text: [''],
    enabled: [false]
  });
}

clearValidators() {
  this.form.get("text").clearValidators();
  this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
}
    
setValidators() {
  this.form.get("text").setValidators([Validators.required]);
  this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

When I load page I have `enabled = false` and `text=''`, but when I click on "Enable" radio button I expect setting validator on `text` field but `text=''` and `form` should be invalid and submit button will be disabled. But when I output in browser console `form.valid` value = `true` and I expect `false`.

What did I do wrong? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is updateValueAndValidity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197806/what-is-updatevalueandvalidity) See especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54045398/215552): "Note: it doesn't go down the tree, only up."

Answer (score 1):

I think `updateValueAndValidity` does not propagate to the child elements. You have to call it on the form control as well:

`this.form.get("text").updateValueAndValidity()`